# checked the radio button when datagridview data is linked to it

Tags: vb.net

'I manage to link my radiobutton with the value M, since it recognizes the first line of my datagrid, but when I change lines the information for "F" does not work

Here is the code to populate my grid view and tell it which row it is on :

```
  Private Sub FrmEtudiant_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        daEtu.Fill(DsEtu1.T_etudiants)
        If DsEtu1.T_etudiants.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            btnModifierEtu.Enabled = True
            btnEnleverEtu.Enabled = True
            Ligne_Courante = 0
            Remplir_Ecran()
        Else
            Ligne_Courante = -1
        End If
        'createXMLProg()
        'DsProg1.ReadXml("programmes.xml")
        'DsProg1.ReadXmlSchema("programmes.xsd")
    Catch ex As SqlException
        MsgBox(ex.Number & "" & ex.Message)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

And this is the code for the radiobutton to be checked :

```
Private Sub Remplir_Ecran()
    Dim ligne As DSEtu.T_etudiantsRow
    ligne = DsEtu1.T_etudiants(Ligne_Courante)
    If ligne.etu_sexe.Contains("M") Then
        rbtnM.Checked = True
    ElseIf ligne.etu_sexe.Contains("F") Then
        rbtnF.Checked = True
    End If
    Try
        DsEtu1.T_etudiants.Clear()
        daEtu.Fill(DsEtu1.T_etudiants)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

[image: When I load the program it automatically checks the value of the first element of my list]

[image: But when I change lines, it does not recognize the value "F" and stays on "M"]

Comment: Subscribe to the `SelectionChanged` or `RowStateChanged` DGV event to call the `Remplir_Ecran()` method. To access the row-bound object, access the `yourDGV.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem` property.

Comment: If the grid is bound to a data source, do so via a `BindingSource`. You can then handle the `CurrentChanged` event of the `BindingSource` and get the current item from the data source via the `Current` property.

Comment: You might also consider creating a user control containing those `RadioButtons` and adding a single property that you bind to. You can then bind the same data to the grid and that user control and you won't need any code in the form.